# Free boundary geodesics as a critical point of the energy functional

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

As a consequence of the formula for the first variation of the energy of a curve, we have the following known characterization of geodesics.

> A piecewise differentiable curve $c:[0,1]\to M$ is a geodesic if and only if, for every proper variation $f$ of $c$, we have $\frac{dE}{ds}(0)=0.$

But I'm trying to prove a *slight* modification of this result, which is given by:

> Let $N$ be a closed submanifold of $M$ and a piecewise differentiable curve $c:[0,1]\to M$ such that $c(0),c(1)\in N$. If $\frac{dE}{ds}(0)=0$ then $c$ is a geodesic which intercepts the submanifold $N$ orthogonally (is free boundary).

I managed to get to,

$$\frac{1}{2}E'(0)=-\int^a_{0}\left\langle V(t),\frac{D}{dt}\cdot\frac{dc}{dt} \right\rangle dt-\sum^{k}_{i=1}\left\langle V(t_i),\frac{dc}{dt}(t^{+}_{i})-\frac{dc}{dt}(t^{-}_{i})\right\rangle- \left\langle V(0),\frac{dc}{dt}(0)\right\rangle+\left\langle V(1),\frac{dc}{dt}(1)\right\rangle$$

where $V$ is the variational field defined by $V(t)=g(t)\frac{D}{dt}\frac{dc}{dt}$, where $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a piecewise differentiable function with $g(t)>0$ if $g(t_i)\neq 0$, remembering that $t_i$ are the partition terms for which $c$ is differentiable.

We know that the variational field is non-zero, and $E'(0)=0$, to finish the proof I need to conclude that

$$\frac{D}{dt}\frac{dc}{dt}=0\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{dc}{dt}(0)=\frac{dc}{dt}(1)=0$$

But I'm not able to do that. I don't know if I took the correct path, I used the main ideas of the proof of the previous proposition. I can go into more detail if needed, but does anyone have any suggestions?

---

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $N$ be a closed submanifold. We say that $c:I\rightarrow M$ is a free-boundary geodesic if $c(a),c(b)\in N \text{ and } c'(a),c'(b ) \perp N$.

The first result mentioned can be found in Manfredo P. do Carmo book Riemannian Geometry Proposition 2.5.

**Edit:** A small change in the statement is necessary to make the question make sense. It was not assumed that $c(0),c(1)\in N$.

**Additional Information:** This question was probably inspired by exercise 1 in chapter 9. You can see the exercise in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1BUa.png).

Comment: You’re on a first name basis with DoCarmo?!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Here some famous Brazilian authors are addressed by their first name, it's not a lack of respect or familiarity. An example is Manfredo **do Carmo**, "_Manfredo's book on differential geometry_" or Elon Larges Lima, "_Elon's book of analysis_". Obviously this does not extend to academic articles. [Look here.](https://bit.ly/3Pivqj0) Anyway...

Comment: Interesting cultural patterns we don’t all know about. Thanks. Quite unusual. I’m still puzzled whether it stays appropriate in an international setting like this.